# MS Access FE / SQL BE Need AutoNumber to populate on form after saving

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, ms-access-2007

So, I have an Access 2007 FE with an SQL BE.  I am using a bound form for both adding a new record, or updating an existing record.

My problem is this: Unlike a local Access table, using SQL tables cause the AutoNumber field ("SeqID") to not be available until after the record is saved.  I have a "save" button on the form, which does various validation steps on a new record, then adds a new record to the table upon successful validation.  At that point, I'm able to get the AutoNumber for that record in my code, but the problem is that I cannot get the form to update/display it in the SeqID field.  Because it's a bound form, I cannot simply update the SeqID.Value.  I need to have this field updated because it is used for other things later on, such as audit trails for changed fields, etc.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried `If Me.Dirty=True Then Me.Dirty=False:Me.Requery`? That is, force a save and then requery or simply requery?. Are you using linked tables or an ADP?

Comment: Yes, I've tried the force save, but no luck, unless I'm not putting that code in the correct event.  It's an SQL BE, so yes the tables are linked.

Comment: Did you try requery? Which event did you use?

Comment: In my Save button code, after the recordset is written to the table then closed, I tried both repaint and requery, but nothing.  I also added the If Me.Dirty=True Then Me.Dirty=False to the OnDirty event, but no affect.

Comment: Is the bound form a **Continuous Form**, if not then you can take greater advantage of your SQL BE by using unbound forms with ADODB, doesn't answer this question but may help database performance : )

Answer (score 1):

Try something on these lines. It works for me:

```
Private Sub AText_AfterUpdate()
   Me.Dirty = False
   Me.Recalc
End Sub
```

If the experiment works, it is just a matter of fitting the steps into the flow of your code.

Comment: Hmmm, doesn't seem to work...Where do you recommend adding it?

Comment: AText is the name of a control on my form. This is the afterupdate event for that control. Use a new form based on your table to avoid complications due to your existing code. I am suspicious of your existing code because the default for MS Access is to save a record, so I do not see how your save button works or quite why it is there for a bound form.

Comment: Ok, I got that piece working by adding it into the next logical text box that would be filled out. The reason I have the save button there is because I don't use any record selectors, and I need certain validation to occur prior to the save.  Using your method works, but actually saves the record before my validation can occur...But shouldn't be a big deal.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Just be aware that the save button may not have any validity. Make sure that a record is not saved if the user simply closes the form or uses some other form of navigation. Try adding recalc to your save button and see if it works.

Comment: That's exactly what I just did, and it works...So in my case, the better solution is adding it in the save button code directly after the recordset is written, so that it passes validation.

Answer (score 0):

When using SharePoint or SQL server, or in fact most server based databases, the autonumber ID is not generated until record save time. With a form + sub form, Access will ALWAYS do a automatic record save when focus moves to the sub form, and thus you don't have a problem attaching child records to these parent forms + records.

In the case of a bound form, the ONLY way to get the autonumber ID is to force the record save. The simple code is this:

```
If isnull(me!ID) = true then
    ' we don't have a record primary key yet, save record
   Me.Dirty = false
End if
```

At this point, you can then use the PK autonumber

```
MsgBox "pk = " & me!id
```

So, a simple me.Dirty = false will save the record, and will force generation of the ID and code that follows is then free to use + grab the PK autonumber at will.